# Listener Home and HomeAsUp buttons not works on Support Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I just use Support Action Bar from AppCompact v7. I'm wrote bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and want to listen this button, but in listener:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    case R.id.HomeAsUp:
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    } 

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When I want to find item from it id, method return nothing. How to listen this buttons with Support Action Bar?

Comment: Instead of R.id.HomeAsUp, try android.id.R.home

Comment: Thanks. This works, but what about HomeAsUp Button?

Comment: I have never seen HomeAsUp as a valid android.R.id... Is this an id you created yourself?

Comment: No, when I choose R.id -> it have HomeAsUp. As I understand it's home button with arrow. I had think, that this two differenr buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```
    R.id.home - res id 2131034117
    R.id.homeAsUp - res id 2131034132
    android.R.id.home - res id 16908332  <-- HomeAsUpIndicator

ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResIdFromAttribute(this, R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator));
ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

public static int getResIdFromAttribute(final Activity activity, final int attr) {
    if (attr == 0) return 0;
    final TypedValue typedvalueattr = new TypedValue();
    activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr, typedvalueattr, true);
    return typedvalueattr.resourceId;
}
```